# <li> contents not showing up on page for some odd reason

Tags: php, html

probably doing something wrong but i can't figure this out i'm trying to put a `<li>` inside of a echo the content is there but the stylesheet it not showing...

```
echo "<li>" . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</li>";
```

[image]

```html
<?php
require 'config.php';
?>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<?php
include 'mc.php';
echo "<div class='usernav'>";
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo "<li>" . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</li>";
    echo '<li><a href="">Members</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="">Messages</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="">Settings</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>';
}else {
    echo '<li><a href="">Login</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="">Register</a></li>';
}
echo "<div class='players'>";
echo "There is ";
echo $online;
echo " Online";
echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the $_SESSION itself?

Comment: What are you saving in $_SESSION['user']['username'] ? Check if there is a class mising

Comment: Everything is there i double checked... the session name is showing

Comment: Even when i inspect the element it says the li is there

Comment: i think you're missing anchor tag between li and $_SESSION['user']['username']

Comment: Guys i'm sorry for wasting your time i messed up the css and put all of it on the a tag... Derp i facepalmed